# Why my query is showing multiple results for avg?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find avg of a user within last 7 days of his activity but instead of showing one avg result for a user my query is showing multiple occurences of every user

```
SELECT temp_user_batches.user_id                AS 
                               user_id, 
                               temp_user_batches.activity_goal          AS goal, 
                               user_activities.activity_date            AS dates 
                               , 
                               Date_sub(Curdate( 
                               ), INTERVAL 7 day)      AS 
                               min_activity_date, 
                               Curdate()                                AS 
                               max_activity_date, 
                               ( Sum(user_activities.time_spent) / 60 ) AS 
                               total_time_spent 
                        FROM   temp_user_batches 
                               INNER JOIN user_activities 
                                       ON temp_user_batches.user_id = 
                                          user_activities.user_id 
                        WHERE  activity_date BETWEEN Date_sub(Now(), 
                                                     INTERVAL 7 day) 
                                                     AND 
                                                     Curdate() 
                        GROUP  BY user_id, 
                                  goal, 
                                  dates, 
                                  max_activity_date, 
                                  min_activity_date;
```

this is the result.

```
9122    10  2016-07-02  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
9122    10  2016-07-05  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
9122    10  2016-07-06  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
9127    3   2016-07-01  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.4500
9127    3   2016-07-03  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
9131    3   2016-07-01  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  135.3000
9131    3   2016-07-03  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  340.4500
9131    3   2016-07-04  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
9134    3   2016-07-03  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
9135    3   2016-07-03  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  9.1667
9136    3   2016-07-03  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  4.4000
9137    3   2016-07-03  2016-06-30  2016-07-07  0.0000
```

my user activity table has 3 entries of user 9122

```
1   9122    10  0   2016-07-02
2   9122    10  0   2016-07-05
3   9122    10  0   2016-07-06
```

so this query should avg but its not.

Comment: did you mean to have `dates,  max_activity_date, min_activity_date` in the `GROUP BY`, it will help to see the expected outcome in that case.

Comment: Why NOW() *AND* CURDATE()?? Surely it's one *OR* the other

Comment: what should i group by on. if remove columns from group by i encounter errors
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'realifex_development.user_activities.activity_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: We don't mean remove **all** columns, only the ones not relevant for your aggregation. For instance, take out `activity_date ` (the only group by field returning different results for grouping) and distinct records should output. Or you can aggregate -max, min, count- this date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple rows with different values of `activity_goal`, yet you seem to want them combined.  So, simplify the query to be what you seem to want:

```
SELECT b.user_id as user_id,  
       Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL 7 day) as  min_activity_date, 
       Curdate() as max_activity_date, 
       ( Sum(user_activities.time_spent) / 60 ) as  total_time_spent 
FROM temp_user_batches b INNER JOIN
     user_activities a
     ON b.user_id = a.user_id 
WHERE a.activity_date BETWEEN Date_sub(Now(), INTERVAL 7 day) AND Curdate() 
GROUP  BY user_id, max_activity_date, min_activity_date;
```

Comment: hey gordon thanks for answer i am using activity_goal beacause I need activity goal for comparison with time_spent. this is a subquery that comes inside select user_id, time_spent, goal from (above query) where time_spent > goal

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this sort of question is actually fairly easy:  **"Take a closer look at the `GROUP BY` clause!"**

Undoubtedly, you have included more group-fields into this clause than you actually intended.

Start by removing the **last** group from the list . . .

Comment: I tried doing that already run into error
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'realifex_development.user_activities.activity_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: *"Meh ..."* whatever you do(!), don't do anything that is in any way dependent on (non-SQL ...) "modes!"

Comment: "It may well be" ... *(and, pardon me, I have **not** "taken a closer look at this," and I am also **un**likely to do so ...)* that you need to resort to *nested queries* ... a.k.a "sub-`SELECT`s ... in this particular case.